# JS: How may I access a variable value inside a function that's inside another function, and that both functions belong to the same object?

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

**In this example, how may I get the value of the i var inside the for loop, into guardarReserva() function?**

guardarReserva() and generarGrilla() are **both methods of the same myApp object**.

```
var myApp = {
    generarGrilla:function(){
        for(var i=1; i<13; i++){
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append("one");
        };
    },
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario').append("two");
    },
```

Comment: Your title gives me a headache

Comment: how would `i` be used in the other one??

Comment: To do something for each div inside each result in the for loop, to use something like $('#horario'+i) in the second function

Comment: Uh... couldn't you just do something like `$('#grilla').children().length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define `i` outside of both functions:

```
var myApp = {
    i:0,
    generarGrilla:function(){
        for(this.i=1; this.i<13; this.i++){
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append("one");
        };
    },
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario').append("two");
        console.log(this.i);//i is now accessible
    },
```

You can also use a global variable:

```
var i;
var myApp = {
    generarGrilla:function(){
        for(i=1; i<13; i++){
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append("one");
        };
    },
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario').append("two");
        console.log(i);//i is now accessible
    },
```

Comment: There is better solution than making it global.

Comment: one downside to property values is that they can't be used during member initialization like globals or closures can...

Comment: True - I've added the global way of doing it back in

Comment: Thanks!! In your fist way, does return an error though: "unexpected token this". This line: for(var this.i=1; this.i<13; this.i++){

Comment: You might need to reload, I edited out the `var` part of that line a few edits ago :p

Comment: Not a problem! Glad to have helped