# How may I call a method of the same object inside .append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

**generarGrilla()** creates an output that has some html buttons.
Each button calls a method that exist in the same object **guardarReserva()**

When I load the page **guardarReserva()** is called without clicking any button, because this line `console.log("whatever "+this.i);` gets printed into the console.

If I do click one of the buttons that have the listeners, nothing happens.

```
var reservasAPP = {
    i:0,
    nombre: function () {
        return $('#h09').val();
    },    
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario'+this.i).html('--> '+this.nombre());
        console.log("whatever "+this.i);
        return false;
    },
    generarGrilla: function(){
        //it loads from html using jQuery(document).ready();
        for(this.i=1; this.i<13; this.i++){
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append("<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" onclick=\"return "+this.guardarReserva()+"\">Reservar</button>");
        };
    },

}
```

Comment: Your [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35639060/1048572) was totally fine. You should use a local variable `i` for what you want to do, not that `this.i` property. Pass `i` as an argument, and use `.on()` to attach your event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually running `guardarReserva()` within your `.append()` function. That is why you see the immediate `console.log("whatever "+this.i);` when you first open the browser.

I think you want the `onclick` of that button to **call** that function. For that (assuming `reservasAPP` is in the window namespace) you can do something like this:

```
var reservasAPP = {
    i:0,
    nombre: function () {
        return $('#h09').val();
    },    
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario'+this.i).html('--> '+this.nombre());
        console.log("whatever "+this.i);
        return false;
    },
    generarGrilla: function(){
        //it loads from html using jQuery(document).ready();
        for(this.i=1; this.i<13; this.i++){
            // ---Change is here ------------------------------------------------------------------------|
            //                                                                                           V
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append("<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" onclick=\"return reservasAPP.guardarReserva();\">Reservar</button>");
        };
    },

}
```

---

> Why I couldn't use "this" and I need to use "reservasAPP"

So, let's look at some of your original code (I'll slightly modify it so it is a bit shorter) and see why it wasn't working.

The line where the good stuff happens is within `generarGrilla`, within the `for` loop where you call the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

```
var i_g = $('#grilla').append('<button onclick="return ' + this.guardarReserva() + '">Reservar</button>');
```

Now you are correct in the idea that when that line of code executes, the `this` keyword is pointing at the `reservasAPP` object. However, what you are doing is not setting the `onclick` event for the button to run `this.guardarReserva()`, **you are *immediately* running the `this.guardarReserva()` function**.

Let's look at a small, semi-related example:

```
var n = function() {
    return 'John';
};

var str = 'Hello, ' + n();
```

Now, what is the value of our variable `str`? Well, we are doing two things:

1. First, we have a string literal `Hello,` .
2. We are then concatenating it using the [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Examples) operator with what the function `n()` returns.

Notice how we are going to use what `n()` returns rather than the literal `'n()'` (string or function). This is because we are actually *calling* the n() function.

So, at the end of the day:

```
// str = 'Hello, John';
```

So, let's go back and look at your original code. What is actually going on there? Well, you are selecting all elements with `id` set to `grilla` (I'm assuming there is only one of those) then calling the jQuery `append()` function. `.append()` can accept a string as its argument, and it'll take that string, and insert it into the DOM as HTML.

Your string is concatenating three different things.

1. `'<button onclick="return '`
2. The return value of `this.guardarReserva()`
3. `'">Reservar</button>'`

Your `guardarReserva` function at the end returns `false`, which when concatenated with a string, uses its .`toString()` method, which in [this case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/toString) returns the actual word `'false'`.

So, if you'd look at your HTML from before, you'd see your HTML code looked like:

```
<div id="grilla">
    <button onclick="return false">Reservar</button>
</div>
```

Which is not at all what you wanted.

Instead, to fix that issue, I had you pass in one long string (which includes the function name you **do** want to call). So, your HTML ended up looking like:

```
<div id="grilla">
    <button onclick="return reservasAPP.guardarReserva()">Reservar</button>
</div>
```

---

OK, so that's why the function was running right away, and why your button wasn't working. So we need to pass in the function as a string for the HTML button to know to run that function when it is clicked.

So, why can't you pass in the string:

```
'<button onclick="return this.guardarReserva()">Reservar</button>'
```

It has to do with how the browser evaluates the `this` keyword within that button.

In fact, let's do an experiment

```
<button onclick="console.log(this);">CLICK ME</button>
```

What happens when I click the button? You can do this experiment yourself. You'll see that it actually logs the literal button. Because within the buttons inline `onclick`, `this` refers to the button itself!

You can doubly verify this with this code:

```
    <button id="button-1" onclick="console.log(this.id);">CLICK ME</button>
```

And see that it logs the string `"button-1"` (aka, the button's `id`).

So, if `this` refers to the button, we can't leave that context to get at our `reservasAPP` object! By referencing the `reservasAPP` object directly (assuming it was declared in your main `<script></script>` tag, thus placing it in the accessible `window` object), we *can* access that object, and thus its inner properties.

---

### SIDE NOTE:

I would use a different method altogether for attaching our `onclick` handler.

I'd use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. Here is an example of how you could define `generarGrilla`:

```
generarGrilla: function() {
        for (this.i = 1; this.i < 13; this.i++) {
            // Save our `this` object for later
            var self = this;
            var button = $('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Reservar</button>');
            
            // Set the `onclick` handler for our button (that isn't in the DOM yet)
            button.on('click', function(event) {
                // Use our saved `self` variable, which points to `reservasAPP`
                return self.guardarReserva();
            });

            // `onclick` is set, insert our button into the DOM
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append(button);
        };
    }
```

Now, when you run `reservasAPP.generarGrilla();`, it'll insert your buttons, and they'll all have `onclick` event handlers.

You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/864233) on why'd some people think it's better to use attached event handlers vs inline JS on HTML attributes.

Comment: Thanks! It does work!!
BTW, Why I couldn't use "this" and I need to use "reservasAPP"?

Comment: @Rosamunda, because you're attaching your event via the actual HTML onclick attribute, instead of say, via a JS method. In the context of the onclick attribute, `this` doesn't refer to that JS object you initialized. I'll write a more detailed response shortly within my answer that'll hopefully clear it up for you.

Comment: @Rosamunda, I went back and edited my answer. Hope that helps in further understanding the underlying issue.

Comment: Yes! I think I've grasped the concept MUCH better now. You've been very kind!! THANK YOU!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reservasAPP.guardarReserva() instead of this.guardarReserva() ?